AWS Step Functions - How are retries triggered?
I've just started using Step Functions which contains a single call to a Lambda. I have configured the Retry Interval, Exponential Back Off etc for the Lambda.
The Lambda   a 400 status in response if it detects any error in processing. I was under the impression returning a 400 error code will trigger a retry in the Step Function based on my above retry config. but this doesnt seem to be happening!
asynch function handler() {
  // Do some processing
  try {
    // Do Some more processing
  }
  catch (exception) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: "Some Error"
    }
  }
}

Since the Lambda itself doesnt "throw" the excetpion but rather catches and returns 400 - is returning 400 not sufficient to trigger the retry?
